# Will different gauges resolve my sound/distortion problem?

Tags: electric-guitar, strings, string-gauge

So, i have a cheap electric stratocaster with cheap pickups and a cheap ampli, now, at start i had 09-11-16-24-32-42 strings on, it was too buzzy when distorted on G/B/E but preatty nice sound on e/A/D... So i changed them with 11-14-18-28-38-49 and yes, now on G/B/E it sounds amazing but e/A/D have really low volume and my ampli distortion doesn't do too much distortion on them...

So, what do you think about something like 11-14-18-24-32-42? Is it a good idea?

Comment: It's odd that you'd get poor volume out of larger strings, as that should give your pickups a *stronger* electrical field. Did you change string materials, like from steel to nickel? You might want to list the exact specs of the strings, including brand.

Comment: Ernie Ball 'Skinny top heavy bottom' (gauges - 10 13 17 30 42 52). Been using them for 30 years. I don't have the chops for an 11 top, but your gauges look like they get relatively lighter as they go down. Of course, you could always manually tweak the pickup heights if there's a general volume drift, of if the strings are overall too near or far. Near would pull at the magnets too much, far would be best, at loss of gain.

Comment: It occurred to me that the higher gauge probably raised the relief in your neck and the action in your strings, which would explain why it’s much quieter now. The guitar probably needs setting up, so I’ve posted an answer pointing to the Fender setup guide.

Comment: You would get that result on your E A D strings if you used bronze would strings which are not magnetic.

Comment: I meant bronze wound.

Answer (score 2):

If the signal balance between your strings is uneven, the problem is more likely in the guitar’s setup than the string gauges. The [Fender Guitar Setup Guide](http://www.fender.com/support/articles/fender-guitar-setup-guide/) will show you the tools you need and what steps to take. For the adjustments I describe below, you’ll need a precise ruler, a Phillips screwdriver, and a set of hex wrenches.

You’ve just changed the strings, which is the perfect time to adjust your guitar’s setup. Because you’ve switched to a heavier string gauge, there’s a good chance your guitar now has too much relief in the neck. That can raise your string action, which can make your strings quieter than they were before. It can also make it harder to play. You fix this by tightening the truss rod a little. This is the most difficult and risky part of the setup. It’s not *that* difficult, but it’s the one place where making a mistake can wreck your guitar, so if you don’t feel comfortable doing it yourself, then take the guitar to a shop and ask for a professional setup. Many techs will walk you through the setup so that you can do it yourself in the future.

The next thing to check is that your action height is consistent from string to string. If your treble strings are making weird noises, they might be too low. If your bass strings are too quiet, they might be (relatively) too high. Get them all a consistent height, somewhere around 4/64 in (1.6 mm) for a Stratocaster.

Finally, check that your pickups are a reasonable height, at an angle that produces about the same signal from the bass and treble sides. If any of the strings make weird electronic noises, the pickups are too high on that side. If one side is much quieter than the other, the pickups are too low on that side. Make sure that your equalizer is flat and your bass/mid/treble knobs are equal when checking this, and check each pickup separately.

Even if you aren’t comfortable doing a full setup yourself, you can at least measure everything. If you find anything way out of balance, like the action height, you can fix just the parts that are causing the most trouble and see *some* improvement.